# Microphone port on motherboard produces noise even when nothing is connected

Tags: linux, windows, audio, power-supply, microphone

I am facing really weird problem. I have a studio microphone with external power that is working perfectly fine on other computers.

My home PC has an issue. It does produce a static noise with any mic or even when no microphone is connected to it.

**Specs:**

- MB: Asus Prime B250 Pro
- CPU/GPU: i5-7400 / GTX10603G
- Power supply: Pure Power 9 400W
- Additional devices in case: TP-LINK Wifi Adapter, 2 SSD drives

Here is what I am talking about:

[image: img]

*Microphone connected*

[image: imgtwo]

*Nothing connected*

What can be the cause of this? I have tried:

- Using both Windows 10 / Linux Mint / Arch Linux with different audio drivers
- Using Mic In port and Line In port
- Using different microphone (and also a headset)
- Using different gain/volume settings (best result when using alsamixer on Linux with line in gain set to maximum and capture volume to something around 10)

Can it be because the PC is not properly grounded and if it is the case how can I find that out?

Comment: It says "unplugged" so i'm guessing its not internally disabled when unplugged (and perhaps not grounded, as you mention), and the floating pins are causing some noise (from interference or something) and it's being internally amplified to a low volume noise (thats essentially random). I wouldn't worry too much about it, I get the same thing on my Thinkpad T430 on Linux Mint (same audio mixer as you have there).

Comment: @QuickishFM Well the issue is that the studio microphone has a serious noise issues (like other mics) which is really bad and it's not happening on other computers for me.

Comment: Perhaps the internal microphone ground isn't grounded and that's why there is some interference from it, but that would be by design and you shouldn't get any static noise from it. I'd err towards the computer port being defective if the issue isn't present on other devices

Comment: On the plus side, you now have an always-on entropy source.